# Вывод информации на печать завершает приложение без появления ошибок C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

При выводе на печать документа через стандартное диалоговое окно печати, программа вылетает без появления ошибок и исключений.
Часть кода вывода информации стандартная:

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    DocumentPaginator paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)fdpvDocumentViewer.Document).DocumentPaginator;
    printDialog.PrintDocument(paginator, "Акт");
}
```

Предположил, что ошибка в установленных драйверах на принтер. Прогнал печать с использованием нескольких принтеров. Выяснил следующее: на всех принтерах, где используется стандартный универсальный драйвер (Из описания: IEEE 1284.4 универсальная поддержка печати) программа, при нажатии на печать - вылетает. Но, при печати из того же текстового редактора - всё печатает хорошо, без ошибок и закрытий. Как можно решить эту проблему??

 Переустановка драйверов на родные невозможна, т.к. используются принтеры, драйвера которых не поддерживают оси моложе Win XP.

Comment: Посмотрите под отладчиком. Хотя, если принтер настолько старый, то может и DEP мешать.

Comment: @Streletz, принтеры hp 1010, и DEP  - это Data Execution Prevention?

Comment: Да. И кстати для этого принтера на оф.сайте есть драйвера под Vista. В теории они могут пойти и под 7 и даже под 10, но **нужно аккуратно пробовать**.